# Python class fields as function parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python class with an `__init__` method accepting different parameters:

```py
class A:
  def __init__(self, foo: str, bar: int):
    pass
```

For different reasons I also provide a dataclass which defines all the above `__init__` parameters as fields:

```py
@dataclass
class AOpts:
  foo: str
  bar: int
```

One good reason for this dataclass is that subclasses of `A` can easily pass through all `__init__` parameteres to the parent class like following:

```py
class B(A):
  def __init__(self, new_param: bool, a_opts: AOpts):
    super().__init__(**a_opts.__dict__)

example = B(new_param: True, AOpts(foo="hi", bar=1))
```

So class `B` doesn't have to repeat all `__init__` arguments of class `A`. And the editor/IDE provides all information about class `A` parameters by the `AOpts` dataclass.

Now to my "problem": I would like to derive the class `A`'s `__init__` parameters from the `AOps` dataclass fields. Because currently both are decoupled from each other. On changes I have to take care that the fields and parameters are equal.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Here what I'd like to achieve in **not working pseudo code**:

```py
class A:
  def __init__(self, <fields_from(AOpts)>):
    pass

test = A(foo="hi", bar=1)
```

It would be great if also the IDE would understand which arguments are allowed in class `A`'s `__init__` method.

Comment: You know about `*args, **kwargs`, right? Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to get fields from data class to be arguments of a function such that IDE would understand it. This would require some meta-programming and IDEs aren't very good at understanding that.

Comment: Agreed, looks like too deep of a magic. Here is the way to do it, BTW, you can give it a shot and see how your IDE reacts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68746003/defining-a-class-init-arguments-dynamically-using-a-previously-defined-dic

Comment: There's no functional difference between `A` and `AOpts`. You can pass an instance of `A` to `B.__init__` and access its `__dict__` attribute the same as you can with an instance of `AOpts`. (Equivalently, you can just define `A` using `dataclass`.)

Comment: @chepner Not exactly. To make `object_of_a.__dict__` consumable by `A` the class fields of `A` must match the parameters of the `init` method. In my practical use case this is not the case. So the dataclass is the perfect representation of the init parameters.

Comment: That information is not present in your question.

Comment: Why don't you just sub-class from dataclasses (assuming A is defined as a dataclass, and then AOpts becomes redundant in that case)?

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that you are complicating things a bit more than necessary. I feel like if you wanted to, you could eliminate the `AOpts` class entirely and merge the declaration into `A`. By having both `A` and `B` as dataclasses, your IDE should be able to infer that since `B` subclasses from `A`, then all the fields of `A` are also acceptable parameters when creating a `B` instance.

For example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class A:
    foo: str
    bar: int


@dataclass
class B(A):
    new_param: bool
```

This way, the IDE can also offer field autocompletion/hinting when you create a `B` instance as follows:

```
example = B(new_param=True, foo='test', bar=3)
```

---

If absolutely you need to retain an `AOpts` dataclass separately, for whatever reason, you can have them loosely coupled but instead create a base dataclass `BaseA` and have both `A` and `AOpts` derive from them, as shown below.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class BaseA:
    foo: str
    bar: int


class A(BaseA):
    def print_hello(self):
        print('hello')


AOpts = BaseA


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, new_param: bool, a_opts: AOpts):
        # if you need to do a shallow copy, use `a_opts.__dict__.copy()`
        self.__dict__ = a_opts.__dict__


example = B(new_param=True, a_opts=AOpts(foo='test', bar=2))
print(example)  # B(foo='test', bar=2)
```

If you can avoid super call in `B` to `A.__init__()` - which is something I wouldn't normally recommend doing, but looks like it might be a good fit for this use case - then again it's a little faster to do a direct assignment, maybe with a `dict.copy()` - that's assuming you don't have a `A.__init__()` or similar defined in code, of course.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from timeit import timeit


@dataclass
class BaseA:
    foo: str
    bar: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        # reverse the string
        self.foo = self.foo[::-1]
        # negate the number
        self.bar *= -1


class A(BaseA):

    # it's strange, but this is needed to get the expected result for
    # `BCallsInitA` (I swear I understood python once upon a time)
    def __post_init__(self):
        pass

    def print_hello(self):
        print('hello')


AOpts = BaseA


class BCallsInitA(A):
    def __init__(self, new_param: bool, a_opts: AOpts):
        super().__init__(**a_opts.__dict__)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, new_param: bool, a_opts: AOpts):
        self.__dict__ = a_opts.__dict__


example = B(new_param=True, a_opts=AOpts(foo='hello world!', bar=123))
print(example)  # B(foo='!dlrow olleh', bar=-123)

example = BCallsInitA(new_param=True, a_opts=AOpts(foo='hello world!', bar=123))
print(example)  # BCallsInitA(foo='!dlrow olleh', bar=-123)

print('BCallsInitA:  ', timeit("BCallsInitA(new_param=True, a_opts=AOpts(foo='test', bar=2))", globals=globals()))
print('B:            ', timeit("B(new_param=True, a_opts=AOpts(foo='test', bar=2))", globals=globals()))
```